# Editing PixelPost Template

Tags: php

I've installed PixelPost (http://www.pixelpost.org/) photo blog script , and I'm using a template which has two CSS files , [Dark + Light] ,

The problem is here ; How should I make the dark CSS style default , in the file "browse_template" it has the following codes :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/simple/styles/dark.css" title="dark" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/simple/styles/light.css" title="light" />
```

which was vice versa , I mean the Alternate stylesheet was dark , I did change this to the above code but still the light style is defualt

here's the full template : [Template Link](http://speedy.sh/AJDhW/simple.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand correctly your question but i'll try to explain.
Everything happens on `styleswitcher.js`

**At first load (never seen the page):**

The js file will determine your "favourite" stylesheet following these conditions :

- It's a `<link>` tag containing `rel=*style*`
- It does NOT contain "alt" string in `rel` attribute.
- It has a title attribute.

So ! With your code, the "dark" theme will be selected at first start.

When you leave the page, the js file is saving the selected favourite style into a cookie.

**On next loads**

The JS file is reading the previously saved cookie and show the last saved style by priority.

If you want to check the correct behaviour of your script, you must **delete cookies** on this domain, then refresh the page. It should see the "Dark" style at first.

Another option to check is to run your Chrome/Firefox in private browsing mode

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: That actually helped a Lot , Tnx